# How to divide a number by $i$

Tags: square-numbers

I was wondering how to divide a number by $i=\sqrt{-1}$. E.g $$\frac{2}{i} = \ ?$$ Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that $i\cdot (-i)=1$.

Comment: If you want a real denominator, you then multiply top and bottom by the complex conjugate (here, $-i$), then work out the result...

Comment: Note that $i^{-1} = -i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{2}{i}=\frac{2i}{i^2}=-2i$$

Answer (score 2):

It is the same as multiplication by $-i$:

$\frac{a}{i} = \frac{a}{i} \cdot \frac{i}{i} = -i a$

Answer (score 0):

Dividing by $i$ is equivalent to multiplying by -$i$.

Answer (score 0):

You could start with a known identity and then work you way backwards to the problem in the OP. For example $i^2=-1 \Rightarrow i=\frac{-1}i \Rightarrow -2\cdot i = -2 \cdot \frac{-1}i \Rightarrow -2i=\frac2i$

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \frac{2}{i} \times \frac{i}{i}=\frac{2i}{-1}=-2i$